# Django Models self reference

Tags: python, django, web, django-models

I need to build a Django Model in which it refers to itself (a list of the same Model type within each instance of this model, sort of like a nested structure), probably within its own definition.

I have looked into ManyToManyField or a possible solution with another model with a foreign key to this Model. What's the simplest way to do it ?

Answer (score 17):

You can use the string 'self' to indicate a self-reference.

```
class Region(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

more in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)